# Automating InDesign to place italicized text in a new paragraph

Tags: regex, fonts, styles, applescript, adobe-indesign

I'm making a book about quotes. Got in the thousands of them. 
They all apear like this:

> Patience is a tree whose root is bitter, but its fruit very sweet.
>   *Persian proverb*

And I would like to make them appear like this

> Patience is a tree whose root is bitter, but its fruit very sweet. 
>   
> *Persian proverb*

So I basically need the program to understand that when the text ends with regular, then have a space and then there is *italic* the space needs to be converted into a paragraph enter (^p). Don't know the exact word for it...

Something in Applescript would be appreciated!

BTW: I use quotes that are made out of many sentences as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've said, it sounds like you can do this with Find/Change. No AppleScript needed.

This worked for me, in InDesign CS6.

[image]

Doing a GREP match means that "Find what" is a [regular expression](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSFB3603CC-8D84-48d8-9F77-F3E0644CB0B6a.html#WS1952D538-1335-4b1d-BA5E-FA5A176FDC9Fa). We're using `.+$` for our expression. Let's break that expression down:

- `.+` will match a sequence of one or more characters
- `$` matches the end of a paragraph.
- The find format will only match text that's in italics. (Hopefully you used character styles for the attributions; if so, use your style instead.)
- Putting it all together, we're finding everything that's in italics at the end of a paragraph. If there are no italics at the end of a paragraph, we won't match anything.

For "Change to" you want `\r$0`.

- `\r` creates a new paragraph
- `$0` is the text you matched in "Find what."
- So you'll end up with a new paragraph before the italicized text you matched.

After you do "Change All" you'll have your italic text in new paragraphs. But some of those paragraphs may start with a space character (if the space was in italics, and matched by the previous "Find What"). You can clean that up with another GREP match.

- Find What: `^` (caret, then space). The caret matches the start of a paragraph. So we're finding all spaces at the start of a paragraph.
- Change to: *empty*.
- This will remove all spaces that are at the start of a paragraph.