# Controlling where paragraphs start and end on a page, in InDesign

Tags: automation, formatting, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I would like the pages of an .indd document to begin with regular text, no paragraphs (nor in the end), and to end with either italicized text or with 2 lines of regular text if the next page has at least one line regular text also. Could someone help me with this?

Good example:

> The fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   *User*
>
> The fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   *User*

Complicated good example

> The fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   *User*
>
> The fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   The fox jumps over

### Next page

> the lazy dog
>   *User*
>
> The fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   *User*

Bad examples:
(begins and ends with paragraph)

> The fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   *User*

-
(ends with regular text)

> The fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   *User*
>   
>   
>  
>   The fox jumps over the lazy dog

-
(begins with italicized text)

> *User*
>   
>   
>  
>   The fox jumps over the lazy dog
>   *User*

Comment: Ummm, lots of examples but can you explain it just a *bit* more? :)

Comment: I'll try, I did complicate it a little.

On the pages will be sentences and author. Sentences are regular text, author is italicized.

A page needs to begin with Regular text, not with Italicized Text.
A page needs to end with Italicized Text or with at least two lines of Regular text.

Comment: And it should never begin nor end with a paragraph (space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting up your [paragraph styles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS9D351498-DAAC-4be1-B4B8-2B6C72FF6CEDa.html#WS60910FA3-2BD7-449d-9904-05CFA551665Da).

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180988/automating-indesign-to-place-italicized-text-in-a-new-paragraph), it sounds like you're still working on your book of quotations. So I'll be basing the examples off of that. You want two paragraph styles: Quotations, for the plain text, and Author for the italic text.

First, get rid of all the empty paragraphs in your document. As you've discovered, using empty paragraphs to create vertical whitespace is problematic. Instead, make space between paragraphs by setting the "Space Before" option on your Quotations style. ("1p0" is one [pica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pica_(typography)), 1/6 of an inch. Use whatever distance looks good to you.) When you use this method, InDesign will never start a text frame with whitespace.
[image]

Then set up the keep options for your Author paragraph style. The "keep with previous" option will make sure that the Author paragraphs are always in the same text frame as the paragraph that comes before them: in this case, Quotations.
[image]

Finally, I keep saying "[text frame](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6fb2a.html)" instead of "page," because that's the object that InDesign pays attention to when applying the keep options. It sounds like you have a simple document where there's only one text frame per page, so the difference is probably moot for you right now. But as you move on to more complex layouts, you can have several text frames per page, and the difference becomes important.

Comment: This I wanted to do in the first place - the only problem was that I didn't make the document in InDesign so I didn't style any text (and didn't feel like applying the styles one by one). Back then I didn't know about using GREP in search and replace yet (and I still have to learn about it more - do you know a good tutorial for this?)

Comment: I don't have a GREP tutorial to recommend. But I bet if you asked over at graphicdesign.stackexchange.com, someone there could recommend one to you.